# Joomla JModelList

Tags: php, joomla

I have a model class that extends JModelList. When I load and register this class in another component using;

```
JLoader::register('ModelClass',  JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_component/models/modelclass.php');
```

Everything works fine when I an using the class in the model class where I import ModelClass.
Whne I try to use ModelClass in the view, I can only see these methods

getUserOptions
__construct
getItems
getPagination
getTotal
getStart
getUserStateFromRequest
addIncludePath
addTablePath
getInstance
getDbo
getName
getState
getTable
setDbo
setState
__toString
def
get
getProperties
getError
getErrors
set
setProperties
setError
toString

Which are from JModelList, and not the ones I defined.

How can I get to see my methods?

Comment: As I can understand, Do you want to use model class of another component into your component?

Comment: Yes. I want to use my model class in someone else's component. When I check to see if the class is define, php says it is defined. Then I check to see the methods available, JModelList methods are available, the methods that I put in my component are not available.

Comment: Try $model = JModel::getInstance('%modelname%','%yourcomponent%Model') replace the placeholders with your names